# Mysql alias in where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my SQL CODE:

```
SELECT `qty`,`unitprice`, qty * unitprice as Stock FROM item where Stock<1000
```

but it is saying:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'Stock' in 'where clause'

how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented under [Problems with Column Aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/problems-with-alias.html):

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a `WHERE` clause. This restriction is imposed because when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

You must instead repeat the calculation within your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT qty, unitprice, qty * unitprice as Stock
FROM   item
WHERE  qty * unitprice < 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an alias in a where condition. It will only be exposed to the next layer up - the calling application, or a parent query if this is written as a subquery.

```
where qty * unitprice < 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding parentheses MySQL calculates the new value first. If not there will be a syntax error

```
SELECT qty,unitprice, (qty * unitprice) as Stock 
FROM item where (qty * unitprice)<1000
```