# extract(month) not working in my query

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to compare results from last month to this month ... but when i try and query with month(Date) or extract(month) it isn't pulling any of the data. here is my query

```
$get_last_month = "SELECT *, 
                        sum(va_clicks) AS last_clicks, 
                        sum(va_imps) AS last_imps, 
                        sum(va_cost) AS last_cost, 
                        sum(va_convs) AS last_conversions,
                        avg(va_posit) AS last_position,
                        extract(MONTH FROM va_date) AS last_month
                    FROM va_HomeLoans
                    WHERE va_list_id='$get_last_camp_name'
                    AND last_month = 11";
$run_last_month = mysqli_query($con,$get_last_month);
$row_last_month = mysqli_fetch_array($run_last_month);
```

it keeps giving me the warning of parameter 1 to be mysqli_result. obviously meaning that it is an empty query. i know that i'm doing something wrong with the query. if i take out the 'AND' statement the query runs perfectly ... so there is something wrong with that statement, but i can't figure out what.

any help would be awesome, thanks in advance!

thought i figured it out ... but still having issues even with using HAVING rather than WHERE

Comment: @chris85 you're awesome ... thank you!

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942307/mysql-alias-in-where-condition